# Laravel, Guzzle - Check if Cookie is set

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I wish to check if the cookie is set, when doing the bottom `getUsername()`. Can anyone help me with a quick fix for this? I've tried for hours without luck.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class CookieController extends Controller 
{
    public function setCookie(\stdClass $request)
    {
        $minutes = 60;
        $response = new Response(view('panel.panel'));
        $response->withCookie(cookie('userInfo', $request, $minutes));
        return $response;
    }
    public function getCookie(){
        $val = cookie::get('userInfo');
        return $val;
    }

    public function getUsername(){
        $cookie = cookie::get('userInfo');
        return $cookie->message->username;
    }

    public function getShopID(){
        $cookie = cookie::get('ShopID');
        return $cookie->message->shopID;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `isset` or compare with `null`

```
public function getUsername(){
    $cookie = cookie::get('userInfo');
    if ($cookie !== null) {
        // do something like set cookie
        // return username
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method `hasCookie()`:

```
public function getUsername(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasCookie('userInfo')) {
        $cookie = $request->cookie('userInfo');
        return $cookie->message->username;
    }
}
```